# How to create open network for Raspberry Pi Pico using micropython?

Tags: python, networking, access-point, micropython

I seem so close to getting it working but every route I take just doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to make an access point from my Raspberry Pi Pico with no password. SOUNDS SIMPLE DOESN'T IT. Here's the incorrect code so far.

```
import network

def create_ap(ssid):

     ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
     ap.config(essid=ssid, password"NEEDS TO BE BLANK")

     ap.active(True)

     While ap.active == False:
        pass

     print("AP active")
     print(ap.ifconfig())

create_ap("APname")
```

Which works all fine until I try to get rid of the password. I've tried `password=""` which seems like it would work but just doesn't, I've tried just having `ap.config(essid=ssid)` but of course that still requires a password when trying to log in from another device?!??

I then found out about authentications mode sort things and tried  `ap.config(essid=ssid, authmode=network.AUTH_OPEN)` and everywhere says that should work and all be fine, BUT NO, just for the laughs turns out micropython just doesn't have AUTH_OPEN???

I've been then weighing up my options and it looks like to achieve this I either have to just get a new device which can run normal python, have a password for my network, or try put some other language onto the raspberry pi pico w (how on earth does one even do that)???? none of which I would want to do.

Thank you in advance for everyone who's trying to advice or breaking the news that it isn't possible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot comment I am posting here. I see documented https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/network.WLAN.html here that you have a "security" parameter. Set your security parameter to "None".

Comment: LEGEND, THANK YOU, I have no idea why I just couldn't see that. Cannot believe I began to think it was hardwired to not be able too